# Authorize.net Ajax Call not Running

Tags: magento-1.9, php, authorize.net

Authorize.net in magento version 1.9.2.1 not making an ajax call to validate the credit card data. Authorize.net is enable from admin panel as well.I don't know what is wrong with it.I am new to this.Below is my screen shot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supposed to. With the default Authorize.Net payment method, the only credit card validation on checkout is inline javascript checks (like invalid expiration date, or invalid credit card number for the selected type). The actual credit card will not be validated as correct until the actual transaction processes, when you place the order.

Part of the reason for this is that allowing users to validate credit cards, without actually placing a transaction, could very easily be abused by credit card thieves.

Comment: Ok. so it will validate the credit card credentials after you click "Place the order" button.right ?Thanks

Comment: That is correct.